# How to fix the footer to make it positioned at the end of the page? (css print)

Tags: html, css, css-position, web-frontend, css-print

I wanted to add a header and footer **on each page** of the printed version of my website, and I used the following method

```
@media print {
 /* the parent container */
 table.report-container {
      page-break-after:always;
  }
  /* the parent container */
  thead.report-header {
      display:table-header-group;
  }
  /* the footer container */
  tfoot.report-footer {
      display:table-footer-group;
  }
}
```

The HTML code is as following:

```
<table class="report-container">
    <!-- the header -->
    <thead class="report-header">
        <tr>
            <th>
                <h1>Header</h1>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody class="report-content">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <!-- body -->
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <!-- the footer -->
    <tfoot class="report-footer">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h1>Footer</h1>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

the problem with this method, that in the last page the footer will not be displayed at the end of the page, unless the page body has filled the intire page. like the following:
[image]

## All I need is to find a way to enforce the footer to be always displayed at the end of the page.

Comment: Please add your full code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this CSS in print as you used.

```css
.report-footer{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  background:red;
  display: block;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<table class="report-container">
    <thead class="report-header">
        <tr>
            <th>
                <h1>Header</h1>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody class="report-content">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <!-- body -->
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot class="report-footer">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h1>Footer</h1>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: This method will only work if I want to put the footer only on the last page, which is not the case.

Comment: No, it will work on each page. Try it and check.

Comment: As far as I know if you use ‍‍‍`position: fixed`, if there is content at the bottom of the page, this footer may cover it – Unless you create an empty area under it.

Comment: @AlirezaRezaee you can add padding/margin bottom to body area. No need to create empty area.

Comment: @MuddasirAbbas OK, your idea is a way to create that empty space. However, they will have to manually quantify to create that area. If they want to use an [**absolute length units**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units#lengths) for this solution, without using a script and only through CSS, a side issue may arise: Suppose, while using `<margin-bottom>` (or `<padding-bottom>`), In some cases, the footer width may be reduced, which naturally increases the footer height to fit the content itself. [Continues...]

Comment: [Continues...] This means that some elements overlap on some screens. In this case, even if you decide to use a script to solve this issue, it is not so right, because we only have better solutions through CSS. Or even if they use [`overflow-y: hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-y), in this case they lose part of the footer.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `%` as it is always inherited from `parent` element.

If you set `parent's` height to `100%` and footer's `min-height` to `100%`, so it will work.

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

Html code:

```
<header>
    this is header part
</header>
<section>
    this is content part
</section>
<footer>
    this is footer part
</footer>
```

css code

```
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

header {
    border: 2px solid blue;
    text-align: center;
}

section {
    border: 2px solid red;
    min-height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

footer {
    border: 2px solid green;
    text-align: center;
}
```

> **`Note:`** Here section's direct parent is body.

Comment: I have tried this solution and it didn't work

Comment: what do you want?

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to determine the dimensions of the `<table>` and it parents (up to `<body>` and/or `<html>`) to do it easily and with no additional changes:

```css
html,
body,
table {
    height: 100%;
}
```

You can use this code in the `@media print { ... }`.

---

Code snippet:

```css
html,
body,
table {
    height: 100%;
}

/* the parent container */
table.report-container {
    page-break-after: always;
}

/* the parent container */
thead.report-header {
    display: table-header-group;
}

/* the footer container */
tfoot.report-footer {
    display: table-footer-group;
}
```

```html
<body style="min-height: 5in;">

  <table class="report-container">
      <!-- the header -->
      <thead class="report-header">
          <tr>
              <th>
                  <h1>Header</h1>
              </th>
          </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody class="report-content">
          <tr>
              <td>
                  <!-- body -->
              </td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
      <!-- the footer -->
      <tfoot class="report-footer">
          <tr>
              <td>
                  <h1>Footer</h1>
              </td>
          </tr>
      </tfoot>
  </table>

</body>
```

Comment: I have tried this but it didn't work

Comment: See the snippet that shows it works, so the issue is elsewhere.